# ArrayList v.s Hash Tables

Tags: arraylist, hashtable

Is there any significant difference between using ArrayList and Hash Tables as both of the two data structures are used for storing dynamic values ?

Comment: Depends on what you need the data for. Arrays are great for ordered, sequential operations, hash tables are great for quick lookups. The best data structure depends on your **how** you plan to use that data.

Comment: if i am asked to pick any random structure then what it should be

Comment: That's a bit like asking to pick either cars or modern medicine. Oh and probably hash tables.

Comment: :D i got your point thanks for quick response :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArrayList is an ordered Collection of objects, the objects will be in the same order that you use to add them to the ArrayList.

HashTable is a Collection of Key Value Pair. Each object in the HashTable is defined by a Key and Value.

Generally the ArrayList is quicker than the HashTable to insert elements in some cases. But when you have to lookup for an element the HashTable (using the key to search) is faster than the ArrayList.

Here you have more information of Collections in Java.
http://mrbool.com/overview-of-java-arraylist-hashtable-hashmap-hashetlinkedlist/30383

Comment: That really isn't true: most hashtables offer O(1) for most insertions, O(1) for lookups, while many lists offer O(1) only for a given insertion (such as an insertion at the end).

As for obtaining elements in the collection, if you need a value from a "key", then hashtables are much faster. If you need a value from a position, lists are much faster. If you need a sorted order, then the list is clearly your friend. This answer is **mostly** wrong.

Comment: Sorry, you are all right. When I said this I wanted to say that HasTable is better for lookup than the ArrayList when you have to search. I will edit my answer

Comment: I'm still not in agreement though about how the ArrayList insertion is quicker in some cases.

Both are O(1) propositions (for an ArrayList insertion at the end), which means neither depends on the number of values in the actual data structure. Sure, an ArrayList insertion could (and is) faster, but the nanosecond difference doesn't matter too much relatively speaking.

It does matter when you have a 10e6-sized object, and need to consider whether an insertion, lookup, or search is O(1) or O(n), or O(logn), etc.

If your time complexity approaches O(n), you add 6 orders of magnitude to it.

Comment: So if you wanted to insert an element at the beginning of an ArrayList, you then have O(n) complexity, because you have to shift each element by 1. Meanwhile, since hashtables have no order, you have still an O(1) insertion.

Comment: Doesn't the existence of ordered hashtables (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7.4#creating-ordered-dictionaries) nullify that stated difference? I'm a layman for intents and purposes, so perhaps I'm misunderstanding.